# how does array should be passed to naiveBayes function of e1071 package in R

Tags: arrays, r, function

I was experimenting with the `naiveBayes` approach.

I built a dataset like this first as an matrix/array:

```
new<-cbind(c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10)),rbinom(20,1,0.5),rbinom(20,1,0.5))     
colNames(new)=c('var1','var2','var3')
```

Now if I run `naiveBayes(var1~., data=new)` it does not work and I get this:

```
Naive Bayes Classifier for Discrete Predictors

Call:
naiveBayes.formula(formula = var1 ~ ., data = new)

A-priori probabilities:
[1] 1

Conditional probabilities:
```

But if I convert them to dataframe like:

```
new1<-as.data.frame(new)
naiveBayes(var1~.,new)
```

I get the mean and sd as it should happen for numeric data.

If I convert the matrix new in factor dataframe as:

```
new2<-as.data.frame(matrix(as.factor(new),20,3))
naiveBayes(V1~.,new2)
```

then it works fine too.

So my major query is how to correctly pass arrays to the `naiveBayes` function.